# Randomly copy 3 files from all sub-directories

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, copy, paste

I'm using WinForms. Under my "C:\image\SourcePath_Folder" directory I have multiple sub-folders. I want to randomly copy 3 files from each folder to another directory with the same name.

Here is what I have so far. This copies all the files from the sub directory to another directory. The code doesn't randomly pick out the files from each sub-folder. How do I select the random files in the first place, and how do I limit it to only 3 files?

```
    private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create all of the directories 
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\image\SourcePath_Folder\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(@"C:\image\SourcePath_Folder\", Destination_txtbox.Text));
        }
        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\image\SourcePath_Folder\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(@"C:\image\SourcePath_Folder\", Destination_txtbox.Text), true);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What part are you stuck on, exactly?

Comment: coping 3 random files from each sub-folders. and putting them into another folder/directory. @rory.ap

Comment: No, more specifically.  What *specifically* don't you know how to do?  Otherwise, this question will be closed as "too broad"

Comment: Specifically, to start of I don't know how to randomly copy certain amount of files from one directory to another. @rory.ap

Comment: No, not "of course" because you didn't mention that in your post.  This is how questions get closed as "too broad" or "unclear".  You need to include all relevant information, demonstrate what research you have done (include links), and ask a clear, narrow, specific question.  I think you need to read this before you post anything else: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern, opts).OrderBy( r => RNG.Next()).Take(3)`  where RNG is a Random object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a small command-line version should be easy to use...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int count = 3;
  string sourcePath = @"C:\image\SourcePath_Folder\";
  string targetPath = @"C:\bar\";

  Random rnd = new Random();
  FileInfo[] randomFiles = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                              .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(count).ToArray();

  foreach (FileInfo file in randomFiles)
  {
    string targetFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, file.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("copy " + file.FullName + " -> " + targetFile);
    file.CopyTo(targetFile);
  }
}
```

btw the usings:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I was looking for 3 random files from 'each' sub folder

Comment: this code search for all files in `@"C:\image\SourcePath_Folder\"` inclusive subfolders and select 3 files randomly to copy... `int count = 3`, results are in `FileInfo[] randomFiles` has three entries

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)